# How to create a horizontal PDF in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, microsoft-excel-2010

What do you have to do to create a horizontal PDF of an Excel document in Excel 2010?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Ribbon, click on the `Page Layout` tab, then click on the `Orientation` button and select `Landscape` from the drop-down:

[image: screenshot showing the tab, button, and dropdown]

Then, go into the `File` tab, click on `Save & Send`, then `Create PDF/XPS Document`, then the `Create PDF/XPS` button:

[image: screenshot showing the PDF menu]

From there, you get a standard Windows save dialog.